# Lowest positive whole number that can not be represented as an IEEE-754 float

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, ieee-754

I'm scratching my head over my teacher's solution to this floating point question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where does that 7 come from and what does he do with the 22?
Is there maybe a better way to solve this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Where does that 7 come from and what does he do with the 22?

7 comes from (1 + width of mantissa_bits).  22 is 7 offseted from the *exponent bias* of 15.

> Is there maybe a better way to solve this?

We can encode values like ±1.xxxxxx<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>some exponent</sup>

When *some exponent*, is *big enough*, the least significant bit of 1.xxxxxx represents the 2's place.

Then the 1.000000<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>big enough</sup> value is followed by 1.000001<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>big enough</sup> and that is 2.0 more, thus the first non-representational integer is in between.

---

Normal values are
-1<sup>sign_bit</sup> * 1.mantissa_bits * 2<sup>exponent_bits - bias</sup>.

Shifting the radix point ".", this can be re-written as
-1<sup>sign_bit</sup> * "1 mantissa_bits". * 2<sup>exponent_bits - mantissa_bits_width - bias</sup>

When (exponent_bits - mantissa_bits_width - bias) is 1, then the least significant bit of ("1 mantissa_bits".) is the 2's place.

```
exponent_bits - mantissa_bits_width - bias == 1
exponent_bits - 6 - 15 == 1
exponent_bits == 22
```

Thus the integer -1<sup>0</sup> * 1.000000 * 2<sup>22 - 15</sup> or 128 is followed by the sought after "first non-representational integer": 129.

Answer (score 1):

The text you posted does not say how the 6 “mantissa”<sup>1</sup> bits represent the significand. Commonly, the bits are interpreted as after a radix point (the general form of a decimal point), so 001001 represents .001001<sub>2</sub> = 9/64. The significand typically also includes a 0 or 1 bit said to be “implicit,” although it is usually a function of the exponent field.

The smallest amount the significand can be changed by is 1 in its low bit, so .000001<sub>2</sub> = 1/64. The exponent portion of the floating-point number scales the significand by some power of 2, 2<sup>*e*</sup>. So, if the significand is *f* and the exponent is *e*, the number represented is *f*•2<sup>*e*</sup>. If we can change the significand by 1/64, we can change the value represented by 1/64•2<sup>e</sup>.

As long as we can change the value by 1 or less, we can adjust it to be any nearby integer. So, to find an integer that is not representable, we have to be at a magnitude where we cannot change the value by 1. Therefore, we want 1 < 1/64•2<sup>*e*</sup>. The smallest integer *e* that satisfies this is 7, since that gives 2<sup>7</sup> = 128, and we have 1 < 1/64•128 = 2.

128 is representable using a significand of 1.000000<sub>2</sub>, where the 1 is the “implicit” bit and the 000000 bits are stored in the significand field, so we have 1.000000<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>7</sup> = 128, and the next representable value is 130, using a significand of 1.000001<sub>2</sub>. So 129 is skipped, so it is not representable, and it is the least such positive integer.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> “Mantissa” is a historic term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. The preferred term for the fraction of a floating-point number is “significand.” A mantissa is logarithmic; adding to it multiplies the number. A significand is linear; adding to it adds to the number (as modified by the exponent).